# Crear un Json dinamico NodeJs

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Hola amigos tengo el siguiente json y necesito transformarlo alo siguiente pero realmente nos e como hacerlo.

```
[
  { organizacion: 'empresa1', usuario: 'andres', rol: 'admin' },     
  { organizacion: 'empresa1', usuario: 'andres', rol: 'superadmin' },
  { organizacion: 'empresa1', usuario: 'carlos', rol: 'write' },      
  { organizacion: 'empresa2', usuario: 'andres', rol: 'admin' },     
  { organizacion: 'empresa2', usuario: 'juan', rol: 'write' }, 
  { organizacion: 'empresa2', usuario: 'juan', rol: 'editor' } 
]
```

a esto debo pasarlo

```
[
   { empresas: “empresa1”, 
     usuarios: [{
       username: “andres”,
       roles: [“admin”,”superadmin”] }
       {
       username: “carlos”,
       roles: [“writer”] }
    ]
   }, 
  {
      empresas:”empresa2”, 
    … 
}]
```

Realmente llega un punto donde ya me empiezo a enredar, y es que no se como entrear validar. Este es lo que hice-

```
let organizaciones = [];
let usuarios = [];

info.forEach(element => {
  organizaciones.push(element.organizacion);
  usuarios.push(element.usuario);
});

organizaciones = organizaciones.filter((item, index) => {
  return organizaciones.indexOf(item) === index;
})

usuarios = usuarios.filter((item, index) => {
  return usuarios.indexOf(item) === index;
})

for (let i = 0; i < organizaciones.length; i++) {

  resumen.push({
    organizacion: info[i].organizacion,
    users: [{
      username: info[i].usuario,
      roles: [info[i].rol]
    }]
  });

}
```

Comment: Y que haz intentado?

Comment: Bueno lo que he intentado es seleccionar todas las organizacion y con un filter traer solo las empresas que hay. Ademas de eso recorrer en un for el arreglo e intentar validar las empresas con un if, pero o sea no se que puedo hacer para crear ese json dinamico Pondre lo que e hecho

Comment: Estos roles... los sacas de alguna parte o depronto son roles que podrian llegar a tener o no estas empresas?, es decir, me imagino que tu decides el nombre del rol, y supongo yo que por tu codigo un usuario puede tener varios roles o tipos de acceso, cierto?

Comment: Me parece que el primer `json` que tienes no es adecuado para lo que necesitas... de por si el problema viene de antes, pero igual se puede intentar hacer algo, pero debido a la forma en la que lo hiciste de primeras, se complica mas la cosa, ya que el formato no es el adecuado.

Comment: Cual seria un mejor formato podria arreglarlo..

Comment: Por cierto ese json viene de un excel y no una BD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muy buenas, creo que tengo resuelto tu problema intentare explicarte como lo he hecho, puede que se pueda hacer menos extenso pero no me da la mente para más.

**Primero tu JSON inicial, que he llamado `tabla`**

```
// la tabla es tu JSON previo
tabla = [
    { organizacion: "empresa1", usuario: "andres", rol: "admin" },
    { organizacion: "empresa1", usuario: "andres", rol: "superadmin" },
    { organizacion: "empresa1", usuario: "carlos", rol: "write" },
    { organizacion: "empresa2", usuario: "andres", rol: "admin" },
    { organizacion: "empresa2", usuario: "juan", rol: "write" },
    { organizacion: "empresa2", usuario: "juan", rol: "editor" },
];
```

**Posteriormente tu JSON de salida, que he llamado `objetos`**

Es un array que contendrá los objetos nuevos creados a partir de la `tabla` o tu JSON previo.

```
// Objetos es tu JSON posterior (resultado)
objetos = [];
```

**Primer `if`, comprobar la `organizacion`**

En este if comprobamos que tu JSON de salida, que he llamado `objetos` cumpla una de dos condiciones, estas condiciones son:

1. Que le largo del array sea 0 - Es decir que este vacío (Solo pasa al principio)
2. Si no esta vacío, es decir ya no estamos en la primera iteración comprobamos que la `organizacion` de la posición sea distinta de la `organizacion` del JSON inicial que he llamado `tabla`

Si cumple alguna de estas estamos ante lo más sencillo que es haber encontrado un usuario y una empresa que podemos insertar directamente todo el contenido del JSON previo (`tabla`)

```
if (objetos.length == 0 || objetos[objetos.length - 1].organizacion != tabla[i].organizacion) {  
    objetos.push({
        organizacion: tabla[i].organizacion,
        usuarios: [{
            username: tabla[i].usuario,
            roles: [tabla[i].rol]
        }]
    });
}
```

**Segundo `if`, Comprobar `usuario`**

En este segundo se comprueba los usuario y se introduce tanto el usuario como el rol si se cumple la siguiente condición:

- Si el nombre del usuario guardado dentro de `objetos` es distinto al de la `tabla` significa que se cumple la condición de poder introducir un nuevo usuario que no este repetido por lo que no hay que comprobar los roles, en caso contrario (el else de este if) significa que ya hay un usuario y solo nos quedamos con el rol, para introducirlo en el array de roles.

dfg

```
if (objetos[objetos.length - 1].usuarios[objetos[objetos.length - 1].usuarios.length - 1].username != tabla[i].usuario) {
        objetos[objetos.length - 1].usuarios.push({
            username: tabla[i].usuario,
            roles: [tabla[i].rol]
        });
    } else {
        objetos[objetos.length - 1].usuarios[objetos[objetos.length - 1].usuarios.length - 1].roles.push(tabla[i].rol);
}
```

**Todo junto debería quedar algo como lo siguiente**

```js
// la tabla es tu JSON previo
tabla = [
    { organizacion: "empresa1", usuario: "andres", rol: "admin" },
    { organizacion: "empresa1", usuario: "andres", rol: "superadmin" },
    { organizacion: "empresa1", usuario: "carlos", rol: "write" },
    { organizacion: "empresa2", usuario: "andres", rol: "admin" },
    { organizacion: "empresa2", usuario: "juan", rol: "write" },
    { organizacion: "empresa2", usuario: "juan", rol: "editor" },
];

// Objetos es tu JSON posterior (resultado)
objetos = [];

// Por cada fila de la tabla (objetos)
for (var i = 0; i < tabla.length; i++) {    
    if (objetos.length == 0 || objetos[objetos.length - 1].organizacion != tabla[i].organizacion) {  
        objetos.push({
            organizacion: tabla[i].organizacion,
            usuarios: [{
                username: tabla[i].usuario,
                roles: [tabla[i].rol]
            }]
        });
    } else {        
        if (objetos[objetos.length - 1].usuarios[objetos[objetos.length - 1].usuarios.length - 1].username != tabla[i].usuario) {
            objetos[objetos.length - 1].usuarios.push({
                username: tabla[i].usuario,
                roles: [tabla[i].rol]
            });
        } else {
            objetos[objetos.length - 1].usuarios[objetos[objetos.length - 1].usuarios.length - 1].roles.push(tabla[i].rol);
        }
    }
}

// Mostrar resultado formateado como JSON
console.log(JSON.stringify(objetos, null, 4));
```

Pido disculpas si lo he enrevesado demasiado puede que haya una forma menos enrevesada pero no he dado con ella, espero te sirva aunque queden por comprobar, como el hecho de que no se repita los roles, pero como no se que necesidad tienes lo dejo ya en tus manos.